# MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "default-token-4gcr4" : object "jenkins"/"default-token-4gcr4" not registered

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I have an on-premise Kubernetes(v1.15.3) cluster(1 Master and 2 Worker nodes). I wanted to run Jenkins agents in the cluster using Kubernetes-plugin feature by keeping Jenkins(version. 2.176.2) master outside the cluster. Therefore, I created a new namespace (jenkins) and followed the configurations mentioned  [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin/tree/fc40c869edfd9e3904a9a56b0f80c5a25e988fa1/src/main/kubernetes). Then, I filled my Kubernetes credentials in the cloud field of Jenkins master configuration. The connection was established successfully. Now, when I tried to to run a Jenkins job as a pod in Kubernetes, the pod is not coming online. The logs from Kubernetes shows:

[Kubernetes-log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWHiS.png)

[image]

```
kubectl get sa 
NAME      SECRETS   AGE
default   1         23h
jenkins   1         23h
```

```
kubectl get secrets
NAME                  TYPE                                  DATA   AGE
default-token-4gcr4   kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3      23h
jenkins-token-7nwbd   kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3      23h
```

The Console output from Jenkins job shows:

[Jenkins-log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7G35.png)

[image]

Has anyone encountered a similar error before?

Comment: Hi can you run `kubectl get sa`

Comment: Please find the output  
`kubectl get sa`
`NAME      SECRETS   AGE


default            1         23h


jenkins            1         23h
`

Comment: can you also run `kubectl get secrets` and please put these information in the your questions with correct format ?

Comment: Can you please make sure everything is deployed in the same namespace? Many of k8s resources are namespaced and therefore only accessible within the same namespace.

Comment: Can you just `kubectl delete sa jenkins` and create new one `kubectl create sa jenkins`. hopefully, its not transient issue.

Comment: @HelloWorld: I deployed everything under the namespace "jenkins". I could still see the issue.

Comment: @SureshVishnoi: I tried deleting the service account and recreating it again. But, still the issue persists.

Comment: It looks like [this github issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/52043#issuecomment-329918942) provides explanation on whats happening, although its old issue so might not be relevant.

Comment: Hi, I am also facing same issue with Kubernetes v1.22.1 and Jenkins 2.289.3. Did you manage to resolve the issue?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, were you able to resolve it?